# Area of a Triangle as a Function of the Hypotenuse

Tags: functions, triangles, area

I can't seem to figure ou the following problem:

A right triangle has sides $x$, $y$ and $z$, where $x$ is the hypotenuse.

$$x + y + z = 6$$

Determine the expression of the function $A(x)$ that gives the area of the triangle as a function of $x$.

The answer is $A(x) = 9 - 3x$ but I need to demonstrate the solution.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE! Since this is your first post, I recommend that you take the [tour of the site](http://math.stackexchange.com/tour). Once you're done I also recommend that you look at [this tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to learn how to produce better looking equations. Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

we have $$A=\frac{yz}{2}$$ from the condition we get $$y^2+z^2+2yz=36+x^2-12x$$ from here we get $$yz=18-6x$$ dividing by $2$:
$$\frac{yz}{2}=9-3x$$

Comment: Would you please explain with a little more detail how you arrived at the second equation?

Comment: we have $$y+z=6-x$$ and that have i squared